How to import tensorflow-text correctly
I have bundle of errors in importing tensorflow-text. I was first trying to import the below versions which were working correctly.
!pip install tensorflow==2.8

but now it says like this
`import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'`

with this version of tensorflow i was installing the below version of tensorflow-text which were fine but as know when i use other version of tensorflow that 2.8 it generates error.
!pip install -q -U "tensorflow-text==2.8.*"

Can any help me with explaining for which version of tensorflow should we use tesnflow-tex.version. As it seems to be a very big trouble for tensorflow handling nlp models.
Thanks
I tried installing many tensorflow versions and then tensorflow text but no match.

You can try with
!pip install tensorflow==2.16.1 !pip install -q -U tensorflow-text import tensorflow as tf import tensorflow_text as text
